# Spark doesn't read/write information from s3 (ResponseCode=400, ResponseMessage=Bad Request)

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I implemented spark application.
I've created spark context:

```
    private JavaSparkContext createJavaSparkContext() {
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
            conf.setAppName("test");
            if (conf.get("spark.master", null) == null) {
                conf.setMaster("local[4]");
            }
            conf.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", getCredentialConfig().getS3Key());
            conf.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", getCredentialConfig().getS3Secret());
            conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", getCredentialConfig().getS3Endpoint());

            return new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        }
```

And I try to get data from s3 via spark dataset API (Spark SQL):

```
     String s = "s3a://" + getCredentialConfig().getS3Bucket();
     Dataset<Row> csv = getSparkSession()
                        .read()
                        .option("header", "true")
                        .csv(s + "/dataset.csv");

     System.out.println("Read size :" + csv.count());
```

There is an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 1A3E8CBD4959289D, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: Q1Fv8sNvcSOWGbhJSu2d3Nfgow00388IpXiiHNKHz8vI/zysC8V8/YyQ1ILVsM2gWQIyTy1miJc=
```

Hadoop version: 2.7

AWS endpoint: s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

(On hadoop 2.8 - all works fine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: Frankfurt doesn't support s3n. Need to use s3a.
And this region has V4 auth version.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

**EU (Frankfurt)    eu-central-1 Version 4 only**

It mean's need to enable it on aws client.
Need to add system property

**com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4 -> true**

```
conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true");//doesn't work for me
```

On local machine I've used:

```
System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true");
```

For running on AWS EMR need to add params to spark-submit:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
```