# 400 Bad Request while trying to access S3 from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I'm trying to read a file thorugh `s3a` from a bucket in us-east-2 (Ohio) and I'm getting 400 Bad Request response:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: [removed], AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request, S3 Extended Request ID: [removed]
```

Since my code works with another bucket in Sydney, it seems to be a signing API version issue (Ohio supports only 4, Sydney supports 2 and 4). So I tried setting the endpoint by adding this to `spark-submit` as suggested in other posts:

```
--conf "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
```

But that didn't make any difference. I also tried adding the same to a conf file and passing it using `--properties-file [file_path]`

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint                    s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

No difference. I still get the same error for Ohio (and it doesn't work with Sydney any more, for obvious reasons).

Comment: This is a hadoop-aws issue. Why was the hadoop tag removed?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218296/877069) might help. It looks like you need to explicitly enable the V4 signature.

Comment: I upgraded to Hadoop 3.0.0 and that did it. So it was a Hadoop bug I'd assume.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in your code:

```
System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
```